# SCCM: see if updates installed succesfully or failed

Tags: windows-update, sccm

Is there any way I can see if windows updates installed correctly or failed. 
Something like windows update history but through SCCM.

I had some trouble with paths and its ineffective running to the clients and controll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to check this, but none of them are really perfect:

- use Reporting. e.g. "Management 4 - Deployments that target a computer", "Compliance 4 - Deployment (per update)", ... etc. Or some other report, there are tons of reports that tell you basically the same things.
- use logging. You can view the status messages and see if the computer installed updates. But this is more useful for troubleshooting and not for checking if all updates were installed.
- the client also writes logfiles into the ccm directory http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693878.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring > Deployments > Select the deployment > View Status. There, you can see which servers/computers installed, in Progress or Failed the installation. You can also see why they failed such as insufficient disk etc